# Android display image from sdcard using AQuery or Picasso

Tags: android, image, android-sdcard

```
message="file:///storage/sdcard0/My Folder/images/Camera_1415795981117.jpg"// image is available at this location

Picasso.with(context).load(  message+"")
                        .into(holder.iv_message_image);
```

have also tried

```
message="storage/sdcard0/Fresh IM/images/Camera_1415795981117.jpg";
```

also tried

```
message="file://storage/sdcard0/My Folder/images/Camera_1415795981117.jpg";
```

and also tried with AQuery

```
aQuery.id(holder.iv_message_image).image(message)
                 .progress(R.id.pb_loading);
```

both picasso and AQuery  load images from url properly but not from local Please help!

**Using Picasso-2.2.0 jar**

Thanks in Advance,
Pragna

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64849/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-pragna).

Comment: /storage/sdcard0/My Folder/images/Camera_1415862492804.jpg String fileName = "Fresh IM/images/Camera_1415862492804.jpg"
;
    System.out.println("USER IMAGE PATH>>>>>>>>>>" + message);
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String img_path = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;

Comment: actally it not loading in every device

Comment: But have you logged that path in Log????

Comment: Yes /storage/sdcard0/My Folder/images/Camera_1415862492804.jpg is logcat path

Comment: Have you added write and read permission in manifest?

Comment: @Pragna Then its strange. Are you sure that in none of any device is it loading.

Comment: no lenovo device not loading sony is loading images but it must not like that

Comment: "but it must not like that" means blur image?/

Comment: mean each device must display i mage na? like that

Comment: Yes every device need to be display image. try to checkout in other device. And you can join discussion chat too

Comment: ok done i have done wwith   final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      options.inSampleSize = 8;

      Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(message,options);

Comment: @Pragna You didn't told me about that. I thought u have decoded it. BTW great!!!

Comment: no i dont fond any error but i just write that lines and suddenly it worked!!!

Comment: @Pragna Oh. Okay. Thats great. It will work because you have applied sampleSize = 8 which means it can decode large image too.

Answer (score 2):

For your solution this will help. To display image from  SDcard you need to convert it to URI first.

```
 Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(message));
 Picasso.with(context).load(uri)
        .into(holder.iv_message_image);
```

Must check your image path `message` is not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The following code would be very helpful and make sure that you are loading **file** when you want to **load an image from SD card**.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(path)).into(imageView);
```